# @each loop to set multiple properties

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to make an @each loop that will set multiple properties for me. In my html, I have four paragraphs in row and as the page goes down I want to adjust the color AND font size for each. Clearly, what I'm doing isn't working: is there something else I can try?

```
@each $p in (
  one #fffff6, $bfs + .1em,
  two #fffff6 - 10, $bfs,
  three #fffff6 - 20, $bfs - 0.1em,
  four #fffff6 - 30, $bfs - 0.2em
) {
.#{nth($p, 1)} {
  background: #{nth($p, 2)};
  font-size: #{nth($p, 2)};
  padding: 1em 6em 1em 1em;
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't creating a list with 4 items in it, you're creating a list with 8 items:

```
$bfs: 1em;
@each $p in (
  one #fffff6 $bfs + .1em,
  two #fffff6 - 10 $bfs,
  three #fffff6 - 20 $bfs - 0.1em,
  four #fffff6 - 30 $bfs - 0.2em
) {
.#{nth($p, 1)} {
  background: #{nth($p, 2)};
  font-size: #{nth($p, 3)};
  padding: 1em 6em 1em 1em;
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

Alternately:

```
$bfs: 1em;
@each $p in (
  one (#fffff6, $bfs + .1em),
  two (#fffff6 - 10, $bfs),
  three (#fffff6 - 20, $bfs - 0.1em),
  four (#fffff6 - 30, $bfs - 0.2em)
) {
.#{nth($p, 1)} {
  background: #{nth(nth($p, 2), 1)};
  font-size: #{nth(nth($p, 2), 2)};
  padding: 1em 6em 1em 1em;
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```